# Where can I found Oracle Database 8.0 windows client to download?

Tags: windows

Where can I found Oracle Database 8.0 windows client to download?

I've looked at oracle site, but I didn't founded.

Comment: Request access to older versions through MOS - My Oracle Support. (Support contract needed)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/winsoft.html

The backwards compatible version.. 8 is deprecated and unsupported for years now..

Answer (score 0):

[SquirrelSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) does have an Oracle-Plugin. But I don't know if it is compatible with 8.0.